# MongoDB Aggregation Function Returning Undefined

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to use use the new MongoDB aggregation features to tally some statistics by date.  Below is a sample of the documents that I am working with, my attempted code and desired result.  The aggregation function retuns "UNDEFINED".  Can someone tell me why that is? And secondly, I want my aggregation function to group results by date in mm-dd-yyyy format.  However as it is currently written I think the code is going to execute the aggregation by the full ISO date.  Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

DOCUMENT EXAMPLE

```javascript
{
  user: "2A8761E4-C13A-470E-A759-91432D61B6AF-25982-0000352D853511AF",
  language: "English",
  imageFileName: "F7A5ED9-D43C-4671-A5C6-F06C7E41F902-7758-000008371FB5B834",
  audioFileName: "F6D5727D-9377-4092-A28A-AA900F02653D-7758-0000083749066CF2",
  date: ISODate("2012-10-22T02:43:52Z"),
  correct: "1",
  _id: ObjectId("5084b2e8179c41cc15000001")
}
```

AGGREGATION FUNCTION

```javascript
    var getUserStats = function(user, language, callback) {
    var guessCollection = db.collection('Guesses');
    guessCollection.aggregate(
  { $match: {
    user: user,
    language: language,
  }},
  { $sort: {
    date: 1
  }},
  { $project : {
     user : 1,
            language : 1,
            date : 1,
            correct : 1,
            incorrect : 1,
  } },
  { $unwind : "$language" },
  { $group : {
     _id : "$date",
            correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
            incorrect : { $sum : "$incorrect" }
  } }
, function(err, result){
    console.log(result);
    callback(result);
});
```

DESIRED RESULT

```javascript
  {
        "result" : [
    //...snip...
            {
                "_id" : "2A8761E4-C13A-470E-A759-91432D61B6AF-25982-0000352D853511AF",
                "correct" : 32,
                "incorrect" : 17,
                "date" : 2012-10-22
            },
{
                "_id" : "2A8761E4-C13A-470E-A759-91432D61B6AF-25982-0000352D853511AF",
                "correct" : 16,
                "incorrect" : 7,
                "date" : 2012-10-23
            }
        ],
        "Ok" : 1
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your first question about it returning `undefined`, there are two problems:

1. You are using the `$unwind` operator on a field (`$language`) that isn't an array.
2. You are using the `$sum` operator on a string field (`$correct`); that's only supported for number fields.

For your second question about grouping on just the date, you need to project the date components you want to group on and then use those components in your `$group` operator's `_id` value:

For example:

```javascript
test.aggregate(
    { $match: {
        user: user,
        language: language
    }},
    { $sort: {
        date: 1
    }},
    { $project : {
        user : 1,
        language : 1,
        year : { $year: '$date' },
        month : { $month: '$date' },
        day : { $dayOfMonth: '$date'},
        correct : 1,
        incorrect : 1
    }},
    { $group : {
        _id : { year: "$year", month: "$month", day: "$day" },
        correct : { $sum : "$correct" },
        incorrect : { $sum : "$incorrect" }
    }},
    function(err, result){
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Produces output of:

```javascript
[ { _id: { year: 2012, month: 10, day: 22 },
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0 } ]
```

You can assemble that into `'2012-10-22'` in code from there.

Comment: Correct on both.  I just tried both parts of your answer and it works beautifully.  Thanks very much! +1